# While using opentelemetry version 1.11. We are facing the issue stating that data is dropped

Tags: python, open-telemetry

We are receiving following error
Due to handshake/connection failure in honeycomb lib even after successful trace and span creation the data is not passed to honeycomb. We are facing this error **Exporting failed. No more retries left. Dropping data**

We are using opentelemetry version 1.11. on AWS. Can anyone please confirm if this issue is fixed in opentelemetry version 1.15 or version 1.16. The error is appearing in ZAP-GRPC.
[opentelemetry zap grpc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EFeR.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be fixed in the latest 1.15 version. In fact, I released the fix in the next patch version immediately https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/releases/tag/v1.11.1